# AWS. How can I control access to s3 bucket from lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

AWS has a large number of buckets that different users have access to. And there is a lambda function that selects data from s3 and gives it to the client via the Api Gateway. The client has the opportunity to specify in the api request from which bucket lambda should make a selection. But how to check that he is requesting exactly the bucket to which he has permission?

In the iam policies, I can only indicate that it can access a specific api resource, but the resource is shared by everyone. In lambda authorizer, I can't get information about the user's rights and permissions (or can I?).

Please tell me how you can solve this issue. Which way to move?

P.S. This should be the authorization of users in amazon, I can't give them my JWT with my data.

Comment: Obviously you'll need a way to associate users with their authorized buckets. You can do this in many ways, including a roll-your-own key/value database (e.g. items in DynamoDB that map user identity to list of allowed buckets). You can then either assert these claims in the JWT or retrieve and test them dynamically in your authorizer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be **your responsibility** to code the authentication and permission requirements in your own code. The person making the request via API Gateway is not an IAM User, so AWS does not recognise them and cannot grant access based on the normal AWS permission model.

Your code would need to:

- Recognise and authenticate the user
- Determine what resources (buckets) that user is permitted to access
- Only provide access to permitted resources

How to do this is your decision. You should start with a way of identifying and authenticating the user.